# jQuery + form issues

Tags: php, jquery, forms, input

I've having some little issues with beign doing a form with jQuery. I'll try to explain it the best that i can.

I've got a button that when it's clicked, it generates a new input. I've succesfully done this with jQuery, naming the inputs by: image-1, image-2, etc.
The thing is, that when I submit the form, the inputs that where added with the jQuery aren't recognized by the page that grab the inputs values, saying "Undefined variable "image-X".

I really don't know why, beucase i've done this, exactly the same way before and worked, but now it doesn't.

Hope you can help me with this issue!

Thanks to all of you

Sorry, forgot to add the code!

This is what I have:
HTML

```
<form method="post" action="update.php?IdMant='.$mant.'" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="'.$id.'" />
<tr>
    <td align="right"><span id="ai">Insert Image</span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td id="images">
        <label>Image:</label><input type="file" name="image-1" /> Order:<input type="text" name="order-1" size="2"/>
    <div class="clear"></div>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<input type="hidden" name="numImages" value="1" id="numImages" />
    <td><input type="submit" value="Upload Image/s"></td>
</tr>
</form>
```

The jQuery code:

```
var i = 2;
var n = 2;
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#ai").click(function() {
        $("#images").append("<label>Image:</label><input type='file' name='image-"+i+"' /> Order:<input type='text' name='order-"+i+"' size='2' /><div class='clear'></div>");
        $("#numImages").val(n);
        n++;
        i++;
    });
});
```

All this way works OK, now, the PhP code:

```
for($i = 1; $i <= $_POST['numImages']; $i++) {
if(!empty($_FILES['image-'.$i]['name'])) {
    $name = $_FILES['image-'.$i]['name'];
    $type = $_FILES['image-'.$i]['type'];
    $folder = "img/";
    $folder = $folder.$name;
    if($type == "jpeg" || $type == "jpg" || $type == "gif" || $type == "png") {
        if(!move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image-'.$i]['tmp_name'], $folder)) {
            $error .= "Error ocurred with ".$name." file<br />";
        }
        else {
            insert_image_to_db($_POST['id'], $folder, $_POST['order-'.$i]);
        }
    }
    else {
        $error .= "Type of image <b>".$name."</b> incorrect.<br />";
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Hard to tell without a crystal sphere. Show some stuff

Comment: Can you post your HTML code?

Comment: Do you use some kind of a framework to create the form on server side ? Do you add the input elements inside the <form></form> ?

Comment: please post your code on jsfiddle or here

Comment: @CyberKnight why not on http://jsbin.com ? Easier, faster. And **Here** absolutely.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan sure y not ....

Answer (score 0):

You should add `table` tag and use it in your jquery . like below

```
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="'.$id.'" />
<table id="mytable">
...
<tr id="mytr">
    <td id="images">
```

And

```
$("#mytable #mytr #images").append(...);
```

EDIT 1:

There is not any `name` attribute like below for your `submit input`.

```
<input type="submit" value="Upload Image/s" name="submit">
```

and you should get inputs something like below

```
if (isset($_POST['submit']){
...
for($i = 1; $i <= $_POST['numImages']; $i++) {
...
```

Comment: well, thanks, but, the inputs added with jQuery works, the one that doesn't is when recovering the form data in the php file.
i don't know if it's because "it's not loaded when the page is load" and then when clicking submit, it wouldn't send the new ones.

may i should make a new submit replacing the original?

Comment: I edited my answer. i tested with `action=""` in my own `php` and did not get any error.

Comment: I tried adding the name on the submit, but nothing, and, what do you mean with `action=""`? my action goes to the page where all the inputs are getted with post

Comment: Please put your codes for getting inputs with `$_POST`.i edited my answer

Comment: `for($i = 1; $i <= $_POST['numImages']; $i++) {

}`
this gives me 3, and jQuery updates well the post of numImages

inside the foreach, i get the inputs, that are files, like this
`$_FILES['image-'.$i]['name']`
but here is where it says it's not defined, except the first one, that that one is the only one it cames when you load the form page.
edit: thanks for your help, seriously